# BigQuery: Concatenate two arrays and keep distinct values within MERGE statement

Tags: google-bigquery, concatenation, etl, array-merge, sql-merge

I am working on a MERGE process and update an array field with new data **but only if the value isn't already found in the array**.

```
target table
+-----+----------+
| id  |  arr_col |
+-----+----------+
| a   |  [1,2,3] |
| b   |    [0]   |
+-----+----------+

source table
+-----+----------+
| id  |  arr_col |
+-----+----------+
| a   | [3,4,5] |
| b   |  [0,0]   |
+-----+----------+

target table post-merge
+-----+-------------+
| id  |  arr_col    |
+-----+-------------+
| a   | [1,2,3,4,5] |
| b   |    [0]      |
+-----+-------------+
```

I was trying to use SQL  [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194619/array-concatenation-with-distinct-elements-in-bigquery) in my MERGE statement

```
merge into target t
using source
  on target.id = source.id
when matched then
update set target.arr_col = array(
                             select distinct x 
                             from unnest(array_concat(target.arr_col, source.arr_col)) x
                            )
```

but BigQuery shows me the following error:
`Correlated Subquery is unsupported in UPDATE clause.`

Is there any other way to update this array field via MERGE? The target and source tables can be quite large and would run daily. So it's a process I would like to have incremental updates for as opposed to recreating entire table with new data every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
merge into target
using (
  select id, 
    array(
      select distinct x 
      from unnest(source.arr_col || target.arr_col) as x
      order by x
    ) as arr_col
  from source 
  join target
  using(id)
) source
  on target.id = source.id
when matched then
update set target.arr_col = source.arr_col;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to expand on Mikhail Berlyant's answer because my actual application differed a little bit from OP as I also needed to data to be inserted if merge conditions were not met.

```
merge into target
using (
  select id, 
    array(
      select distinct x 
      from unnest(
          /*  
          concat didn't work without case-when statement for 
          new data (i.e. target.id is null) 
          */
          case when target.id is not null then source.arr_col || target.arr_col 
          else source.arr_col
          end
      ) as x
      order by x
    ) as arr_col
  from source 
  left join target /* to be able to account for brand new data in source */
  using(id)
) source
  on target.id = source.id
when matched then
update set target.arr_col = source.arr_col
when not matched insert row
```

;