# BigQuery query which returns distinct array union of all arrays where the object ID is the same

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I would like to query BigQuery where two columns are returned, a distinct object ID column, and a distinct combination of array values based on values of the arrays where the object IDs were the same.

For example, say I have this table in BigQuery:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| object_id |  array    |
+-----------+-----------+
| a         | 1,2,3,4,5 |
| a         | 2,3,4,5,6 |
| b         | 9,8,7,6   |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I would like to run a query that returns the following data:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| object_id |  array      |
+-----------+-------------+
| a         | 1,2,3,4,5,6 |
| b         | 9,8,7,6     |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I think the query should be something *similar* to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194619/array-concatenation-with-distinct-elements-in-bigquery) but am a little unclear on how to get the distinct object ID with the distinct combination of array elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_concat_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_concat_agg):

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' id, [1,2,3,4,5] arr UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', [2,3,4,5,6] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', [9,8,7,6]
)
SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT x FROM UNNEST(concatenated) as x) as a
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(arr) as concatenated
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY id
)
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below [slim] solution

```
select id, array_agg(distinct el) as arr
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(arr) el
group by id
```